# Converting jQuery live to on with find

Tags: jquery

How to convert this to use jQuery .on from .live:

```
    var $elementHelper = $('.inline_docxdiv [class^="element_helper"]');

$elementHelper.find('.display-explanation').live('click',(function() {

    //code here

    }));
```

I tried this and didn't work:

```
    var $elementHelper = $('.inline_docxdiv [class^="element_helper"]');

$(document).on('click', $elementHelper.find('.display-explanation'), function () {

    //code here

    });
```

Comment: The second parameter should be a `string` and not an `object`.

Comment: Damn how i miss that one..thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.inline_docxdiv [class^="element_helper"] .display-explanation', function () {

    //code here

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it like,

```
$elementHelper.on('click', '.display-explanation', function () {
   //code here
});
```

**Syntax** is,

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

**or**

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )
```

Read [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)